# Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "address"

Tags: solidity-0.5.x

I am using solidity 0.5.0 when i compile code i am throwing exception as 
Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "address".

code is working fine in remix IDE

[image]

and my code is as

```solidity
function orderItem(uint _itemid,string memory _itemname ) public returns(address){
    address uniqueId = address(sha256(msg.sender,'block.timestamp'));
    packagemapping[uniqueId].isuidgenerated = true;
    packagemapping[uniqueId].itemid = _itemid;
    packagemapping[uniqueId].itemname = _itemname;
    packagemapping[uniqueId].transactionstatus = " Your package is ordered and is under processing ";
    packagemapping[uniqueId].orderstatus = 1;
    packagemapping[uniqueId].customer = msg.sender;
    packagemapping[uniqueId].ordertime = "block.timestamp";
    return uniqueId;
}
```

error line: `address uniqueId = address(sha256(msg.sender,'block.timestamp'));`

Comment: Try `address(uint256(sha256(msg.sender,'block.timestamp')));`

Comment: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1. This function requires a single bytes argument. Use abi.encodePacked(...) to obtain the pre-0.5.0 behaviour or abi.encode(...) to use ABI encoding.

Comment: i also tried address(sha256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender,'block.timestamp')));

Comment: Try `keccak256` instead of `sha256`.

Comment: no even this didn't help

Comment: if i give function like this ....function orderItem(uint _itemid,string  _itemname ) public returns(address) it is working fine but at  string  _item name ide is throwing error as Data location must be "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```solidity
address uniqueId = address(bytes20(sha256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender,'block.timestamp'))));
```

Also, why `'block.timestamp'` is in quotes?  Maybe it should be:

```solidity
address uniqueId = address(bytes20(sha256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender,block.timestamp))));
```

Comment: Follow up question after using above solution , packagemapping[uniqueId].ordertime = 'block.timestamp';   IDE is showing error at block.timestamp as Type literal_string "block.timestamp" is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.

Comment: Just remove quotes around `block.timestamp`.

Comment: tried it didn't work

Comment: How `packagemapping` is defined?

Comment: Thanks it worked but showing warning , checked with warning where it can be ignored . Doesn't effect compiling in smartcontract